# How to check if the event is not raised by some anchor/hyperlink click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

Please refer the below snippet

```
if (this.type.fullCarousel) {
  window.onbeforeunload = () => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}
```

I need to stop the execution of `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` when this event is raised by some hyperlink click.

Currently, when anyone clicks on hyperlink of the page, it is first taken to top of the page & redirects.

How do I check that this line is executed only if the event is not raised by some anchor click?

Thanks!

Comment: You could check if either the event is a click event or if `event.target` is an anchor tag

Comment: "*if the event*" - what's the event?  `$(this).is("a")` might be enough

Comment: @empiric Thanks for hinting. Please check the implementation in the post

Answer (score 0):

Getting the hint from the @empiric comments. This is how I addressed the required

```
if (this.type.fullCarousel) {
        window.onbeforeunload = () => {
            if (event.target.tagName.toString().toLowerCase() == "a" &&
                event.target.href.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("http")) {
                    break;
                }
            window.scrollTo(0, 0)
        }
```